# Unable to Assign Primary Key Value to Another table column of same data type

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I am unable to store the "ID" value of Student into "StudentID" of StudentCourses table.Its returning no error, data types are also matching.

ViewModel: StudentVM

```
public class StudentVM
    {
        public Student student { get; set; }
        public SelectList Courses { set; get; }
        public int SelectedCourseID { get; set; }
        public StudentCourses studentCourse { get; set; }

    }
```

The "St.Id" is giving me a value however its value is not getting transferred to "StudentID" field of StudentCourse table,without any error message.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection Form,StudentVM Vm) {
           // string strDDLValue = Vm.SelectedCourseID;

            Student st = new Student() {Name=Vm.student.Name };

            var stname=st.Name;

            int stid = st.Id;  //No transfer of value takes place.stid is null

            StudentCourses stc = new StudentCourses() { CourseID = Vm.SelectedCourseID, StudentID = st.Id };

            db.Students.Add(st);

            db.StudentCourses.Add(stc);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

The Object St is indeed returning values of input. please have a look.

[image]

Comment: All you have done is initialized a new instance of `Student` and set its `Name` property. Nowhere have you set its `Id` property so `int stid = st.Id` is going to return `null` or `0` depending where the property is `int?` or `int` (and a view model should not contain a data model when editing!)

Comment: St.Id does return a value please look at the pic i added.

Comment: Then you `Student` must have a default constructor setting the value which means that `stid` will be 2004 (not null as your claiming!) or your reading that value in the debugger after the `db.SaveChanges();` line.

Comment: My issue is  that value in st.Id is not being transferred to stid . Transfer of value is not occurring,that is the main issue. whereas transfer of st.Name to stname is occurring without any issues. Moreover db.savechanges() is happening at the last,My st.Id value is generated after instantiation of student class,i am assuming this has nothing to do with db.savechanges()

Comment: Of course it is only assigned after you call `SaveChanges()` - that is when the database assigns it!. What are you expecting to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not assign the ID's but the **entire entities** to eachother.

```
StudentCourses stc = 

new StudentCourses() { CourseID = Vm.SelectedCourseID, Student = st };
```

This way, upon SubmitChanges() LsS will know the ID and assign the appropriate relations within a single transaction.